# What is the right way to config Flink parallelism?

Tags: apache-flink

I am working on a Flink project which requests lots of computation in each operator. I am not sure how should I config the parallelism. It looks like Flink would like to deploy all the instances of each operator to the first taskmanger first and then deploy other parallelisms to the rest of taskmanagers accordingly.

This approach ends up waste lots of resources. For example, assume we total have 4 taksmanagers. We have operators A and B, the parallelism is 2 and 2. And Operator B request lots of resource for computation. Is it possible to deploy operator A in taskmanager 1 and 2 and deploy operator B in taskmanger 3 and 4. This helps to utilize the resources. Otherwise, operators A and B are going to share the resource in the same taskmanager.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for the configuration setting `cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots: true`. This strategy tries to spread out the slots evenly across all available TaskExecutors.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I tried this. But it does help. My app is running in Flink 1.11. All subtasks go to one TM and only subtasks that have more than 1 parallelism go to another TM.